# State doesn't update to true onClick (React)

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to get a component to render when a state variable is true. The issue I have is when I register the click it doesn't seem to update the state variable to true, it just remains false.

Here is the click event:

```
const [isShown, setIsShown] = useState(false);


{Object.entries(key[1]).map((header, index) => (
                <div
                  className="hover:bg-purple-50 group"
                  key={"row-" + index}
                  onClick={(e) => {
                    updateSelectedNode(header);
                    setIsShown(true);
                  }}
                 >
```

Here is where I am trying to render it:

```
  const ToggleItem = (props: {
    header: LinkHeader;
    id: string;
    selectedNode: LinkHeader | null;
    updateSelectedNode: Function;
  }) => {
    const { header, id, selectedNode, updateSelectedNode } = props;
    return (
      <>
        [...]

          {selectedNode == header && isShown && (
            <div>
              {authStatus === "authenticated" ? (
                <LinkView
                  node={header.codeNode as CodeNode}
                  state={NOTEBOOK_INITIAL_STATE}
                  dispatch={dispatch}
                  userID={userID}
                  expandAll={false}
                />
              ) : (
[...]
</>
```

Comment: how does isShown get passed to ToggleItem??

Comment: selectedNode and header both look like objects, are you sure selectedNode will ever `==` header?